# How to substitute line containing character with text stored in variable with sed?

Tags: shell-script, sed, variable-substitution

I have a file entry.txt with a text such as

```
$ cat entry.txt 
>Main entry
This is some text to try
how to substitute the first
line of the text.
```

I would like to substitute the first line by searching for the character `>` and add some text stored in a variable:

```
$ var=TITLE
$ sed -i "s/>*/$var/" entry.txt 
$ cat entry.txt 
TITLEMain entry
TITLEThis is some text to try
TITLEhow to substitute the first
TITLEline of the text.
```

How can I

1. substitute the whole line containing `>` and not `>` alone
2. substitute only the first line and not the other lines?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to use awk instead of sed for this as awk understands literal strings while sed doesn't so what any sed command does with a variable will vary a lot depending on the contents of the variable, eg. try the currently accepted solution if `var` contains `foo&bar`. See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern should `^>.*` to match only those lines starting with `>` (`^>`) and matching everything else in that line (`.*`). So:

```
sed -i "s/^>.*/$var/" entry.txt
```

Comment: Really? It doesn't appear to implement the first line only constraint, and doesn't replace the entire line if '>' is not the first character.

Comment: @symcbean in all likelihood it's [a FASTA file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) (text processing problems on such files are fairly common here even though [bioinformatics.se] exists), and neither of those requirements are _really_ what are needed. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you had provided the expected output, although I think I can guess most of what you want. Your test cases only addresses the requirement to replace '>', not the first line constraint. It also doesn't address the scenario where '>' is not the first character in the line. It's easier to test sed with '-e' (change stdin to stdout) rather than '-i' (edit file in place).

Maybe we try a different test case:

```
>Main entry>
This is some text to try
>how to substitute the first
line of the text.
```

> sed -i "s/>*/$var/" entry.txt

Here the pattern says to match zero or more instances of '>', but you really want to match at least one instance. How do you intend to handle multiple instances?, should it only be matched at the sart of the line?)

```
var=INJECT
sed -e "s/.*>.*/$var/" <entry.txt
INJECT
This is some text to try
INJECT
line of the text.
```

This looks a bit better.

However to get sed to *only* change the first line is a lot more difficult. With the Gnu sed, this is possible:

```
sed -e "0,/.*>.*/s//$var/" <entry.txt
INJECT
This is some text to try
>how to substitute the first
line of the text.
```

It is *probably* possible by some other means in traditional sed, but I would already have given up and used awk for this.

Comment: Regarding "to get sed to only change the first line is a lot more difficult." -  `sed "1 s/>*/$var/"` should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

If we want to change first record if `>` appears at start of record, then the following may be used:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" '/^>/ && NR==1{$0 = var}1'
```

If we want to change first line of first instance of where `>` appears at the start of line then the following command may be used:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" '/^>/ && !a{$0 = var; a++}1'
```